# Image preview not display in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

Upload the customer image in the backend.But not display the image preview.(magento 2.2.5)

I'm using this extension

> https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar

How to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have u check log files under Magento var/log and var/report

Comment: Yes...... It does not display any error

Comment: `log files under Magento var/log and var/report`, Also check  browser console?

Comment: I'm trying to hit the image url in browser ...it displayed  "The image http://127.0.0.1/XXX.com/admin/customer/index/viewfile/image/dG1wL0hELVdhbGxwYXBlcnMtODkuanBn/key/0d007d653acc339cb1b6cbacfe989d4c4e49ee3048fe05e73e727116809eed1fcannot be displayed. because the image contains errors"

Comment: But the image saved in pub/media/ customer folder